# How to use asp:BoundField in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm trying to set id of `<asp:BoundField>` control. But I recieve message:

> Id attribute is Invalid for tag that are not inherited from control.

I want to set visibility of this tag in varyous cases. How can I do it?

The following code behind code snippet:

```
public String FilterByType
{
    get { return (ViewState["FilterByType"] as String); }
    set
    {
        if ((ViewState["FilterByType"] as String) != value)
            ViewState["FilterByType"] = value;                
    }
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (FilterByType == "in")
      {
          //set visible on
      }
}
```

And there is webform snippet:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds"
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to do this. Also your markup.

Comment: Can you please give me your code?

Comment: @NicholasV. See updated

Comment: BoundField can't have an ID. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (FilterByType == "in")
      {
          gv.DataSource = dt;
          gv.DataBind();
      }
}
```

Here dt is datable with have sds and description field

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:BoundField>
```

does not have an Id attribute.

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want to set the visibility of a particular bound field, then pick it up using the DataField it is bound to in OnItemDataBound method.

Could give you the code when I get back home.

Comment: I'll give you an up-tick if you provide the code @Alok ;)

Comment: At this pint it looks like I never made it to my home :P. Let me get my thoughts together and will summon some code for you if you need it.